# Error Post Nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Hola amigos me sale este error, nose porque , estoy viendo mi codigo y todo esta correcto.

```js
{
    "code": "EREQUEST",
    "number": 515,
    "lineNumber": 10,
    "state": 2,
    "class": 16,
    "serverName": "CHRIS",
    "procName": "usp_crearUsuarios",
    "originalError": {
        "info": {
            "number": 515,
            "state": 2,
            "class": 16,
            "message": "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'nombre', table 'Aplicativo.dbo.tb_usuarios'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.",
            "serverName": "CHRIS",
            "procName": "usp_crearUsuarios",
            "lineNumber": 10,
            "name": "ERROR",
            "event": "errorMessage"
        }
    },
    "name": "RequestError",
    "precedingErrors": []
}
```

Noodejs:
-DAO:

```js
let sql = require('mssql');
var helper = require('./../../../Helper/helper');

exports.listarUsuarios = (ok, error) => {

    var parameters = []
    helper.query2(sql, "usp_listarUsuarios", parameters, ok, error)
}

exports.crearUsuarios = (parametro, ok, error) => {
    var parameters = [];
    parameters.push({ name: "nombre", values: parametro.nombre })
    parameters.push({ name: "email", values: parametro.email })
    parameters.push({ name: "contrasena", values: parametro.contrasena })
    parameters.push({ name: "imagen", values: parametro.imagen })
    parameters.push({ name: "rol", values: parametro.rol })
    parameters.push({ name: "google", values: parametro.google })
    console.log("para", parameters);
    helper.query2(sql, "usp_crearUsuarios", parameters, ok, error)
}
```

-Constroller:

```js
var UsuariosDAO = require('./../DAO/UsuariosDAO');


exports.listarUsuarios = (req, res) => {
    function ok(lista) {
        res.status(200).send(lista)
        console.log(lista);

    }

    function error(error) { res.status(404).send(error) }
    UsuariosDAO.listarUsuarios(ok, error)

}

exports.crearUsuarios = function(req, res) {
    function ok(lista) { res.status(200).send(lista) }

    function error(error) { res.status(404).send(error) }
    const parametro = {
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        email: req.body.email,
        contrasena: req.body.contrasena,
        imagen: req.body.imagen,
        rol: req.body.rol,
        google: 0
    }
    console.log(parametro);
    UsuariosDAO.crearUsuarios(parametro, ok, error)

}
```

-La ruta del Puerto

```js
var express = require("express")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var methodOverride = require("method-override")
var cors = require('cors')
var rutaServer = require('../../Helper/config').rutaServer;

var puerto = process.env.port || 2018;

/*controller*/
var usuarioControle = require('./Controller/UsuariosController');

/*service*/
var app = express()
var router = express.Router()
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Servicios Rest - RestUsuarios")
})

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(methodOverride())
app.use(router)

var api = express.Router()

api.route('/listadousuarios').get(usuarioControle.listarUsuarios);
api.route('/registrarUsuarios').post(usuarioControle.crearUsuarios);
app.use(rutaServer + '/usuarios', api)

app.listen(puerto, function() {
    console.log('Servidor escuchando en puerto ' + puerto)
})
```

Y mi procedured

```js
create database Aplicativo
go
use Aplicativo
create table tb_usuarios(
idusuario int primary key identity(1,1),
nombre varchar(300) not null,
email varchar(200) not null unique,
contrasena varchar(200) not null,
imagen varchar(200),
rol varchar(200) not null,
google bit
)


create proc usp_crearUsuarios
@nombre varchar(300),
@email varchar(200) ,
@contrasena varchar(200),
@imagen varchar(200),
@rol varchar(200),
@google bit
as
begin
insert into tb_usuarios(nombre,email,contrasena,imagen,rol,google) values(@nombre,@email,@contrasena,@imagen,@rol,@google)
end
```

Comment: ¿ Que te muestra tu `console.log("para", parameters);` ? Claramente, te está faltando alguno por indicar.

Comment: Me sale lo que inserte en raw, osea : para [ { name: 'nombre', values: 'Alexis' },
  { name: 'email', values: 'awdawd' },
  { name: 'contrasena', values: 'awdawd' },
  { name: 'imagen', values: 'Amd' },
  { name: 'rol', values: 'req.body.rol' },
  { name: 'google', values: 0 } ]

Comment: Segun tu código, tienes 4 campos `NOT NULL`: `nombre`, `email`, `contrasena` Y `rol`. El error indica claramente que al menos 1 está llegando como `NULL`. Si alguien quisiera ayudarte, tener los `console.log( )` en los puntos por lo que van pasando los datos **cabe la posibilidad de que le fuera útil**. Buena suerte, y un saludo.

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías mostrar el código de `helper.query2()`? Saludos